# more than one elementID parameter HTML DOM getElementById() Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

can you have more than one elemenID parameter HTML DOM getElementById() Method?and how?
Base on w3schools this is the syntax of HTML DOM getElementById() Method but it deosn't show in a situation were in you need to call mutiple ID's.

Syntax
document.getElementById(elementID)

[image]

I need to get the element of label 1-6 to form this output:

***199 Freestone Road, Sladevale QLD 4370, Australia***

Comment: Why do you even use ID's for that task? Either use classes on your form input elements or just iterate them.

Comment: it's the only method that we were introduce to sir during our previous subject, we haven't tackled multiple ID's but I'm looking forward to learn them.

Comment: What's the problem with using `getElementById()` six times? For the purpose you mention you need to treat the elements somewhat individually anyway, so that you can insert commas in appropriate places.

Comment: document.getElementById('street_number', 'route','locality','administrative_area_level_1','postal_code','country').value; i did something like this sir, but now I know it's not suited for the task that we are asked to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `getElementById` only allows a single element to be specified.

The more recent (i.e. less well supported) `querySelectorAll` method accepts a selector, which can include multiple ids.

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six');
```

But you would probably be better off just calling `getElementById` in a loop (you could store your id values in an array).

Better still would be to adjust the markup. If you have a group of elements, then use some kind of grouping mechanism.

e.g.

```
 // Make them all members of a class
 var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

 // Put them all in a container
 var nodeList = document.getElementById('someContainer').getElementsByTagName('label');
```

Comment: sir thank you it's very informative, are class is about to end, may I ask if you could link me to some fiddle or some sites for more examples so I can further study/tweak them at home.thank you again sir